# Render link for association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activescaffold

I have an Order model which has one Cart model. In orders#edit form I want to have a link to the carts#show page of the belonging cart.

The [documentation](https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold/wiki/API%3a-Column#form_ui-v11) mentions several UI elements which can be rendered, but I don't see things which can render links.

My current setup is:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  active_scaffold :order do |conf|
    conf.columns = [:name, :cart]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Do this in two ways

```
get "orders#edit", :to=> "cart#show"
```

or, just type rake routes in your terminal and you might see something like order_edit and cart_show,then do this

```
get order_edit_path,:to=> cart_show_path
```

Comment: Sorry but I was asking how to render a link in edit form. Your answer is to do with route.